# Get random images with other table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

People and images

Table People

```
+----+--------+----------+
| id | name   | lastname |
+----+--------+----------+
|  1 | Jhon   | Smith    |
|  2 | George | Mutt     |
|  3 | Peter  | Law      |
+----+--------+----------+
```

Table images

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | id_people | img        |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  1 |         1 | demo04.jpg |
|  2 |         2 | test1.jpg  |
|  3 |         2 | orange.jpg |
|  4 |         2 | flow.png   |
|  5 |         3 | darth.png  |
|  6 |         3 | green.png  |
+----+-----------+------------+
```

I need get all people with one image random.

For example, the good result it's.

```
+----------------------------+
1 | Jhon   | Smith | demo04.jpg
2 | George | Mutt  | orange.jpg
3 | Peter  | Law   | green.png
+----------------------------+
```

Or the other result.

```
+----------------------------+
1 | Jhon   | Smith | demo04.jpg
2 | George | Mutt  | test1.jpg
3 | Peter  | Law   | darth.png
+----------------------------+



I used this sql query 

SELECT * 
FROM   `people` p 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT * 
                   FROM   images 
                   ORDER  BY Rand() 
                   LIMIT  1)i 
               ON i.id_people = p.id 
WHERE  1
```

But only return one row.

```
+----+--------+----------+----+-----------+------------+
| id | name   | lastname | id | id_people | img        |
+----+--------+----------+----+-----------+------------+
|  2 | George | Mutt     |  3 |         2 | orange.jpg |
+----+--------+----------+----+-----------+------------+
```

What's error?

Comment: Did you want a _different_ image for each of the 3 people?  If so, I think the chosen answer is flawed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery instead of a `join` in this case:

```
SELECT p.*,
       (select i.img
        from images i
        where i.id_people = p.id 
        order by rand()
        limit 1
       ) as img
FROM   `people` p ;
```